# Overlaying Image Textures

Tags: texturing

So, I'll try to keep it simple. I'm just trying to overlay a transparent image texture on top of another image texture. I've followed various examples on this and I'm just not getting the same results. I've included my node set-up and what my model looks like as a result.

I will also note that although I've got each image texture set to a specific UV map, the texture currently displayed on the model changes as I click between them. Not entirely sure why that's happening either lol...

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I haven't checked your file but in the first screenshot, the values for the UV maps are red. That's an error and Blender tries to tell you they are invalid. Are you sure the names are correct?

Comment: I think Blunder is correct - you changed the named of your uv maps to _HeadMap_ and _EyeMap_ respectively, but didn't change the nodes to reflect that (as they say _UVMap_ and _UVMap.001_). Click the box and pick the maps by name.

Comment: @Blunder & Christopher, swapped the UVs and nothing changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You need to fix the UV names in the node setup, and choose *Viewport Shading* mode *Material Preview* or *Rendered*.**

In the *Shader Editor*, you will see that the names of the UV maps for UV map nodes are displayed in red. That's an error and Blender tries to tell you they are invalid. Choose the correct names for the UV maps.

Nothing will change because you are still in *Viewport Shading* mode is still set to *Solid* with *Color* set to *Texture* as you can see here:

[image: shading type solid with shading options]

This shading mode uses the *Workbench* render engine which is a very simple render engine. It uses the image texture of the active *Image Texture* node and displays it. This causes the texture to change when you click on the nodes.
It's useful for texture painting so you see what you paint. But it also simply uses the transparency of the image - which hides the face.

To see the result of your node setup, switch the *Viewport Shading* mode (<kbd>Z</kbd>) to *Material Preview* or *Rendered*. There are also options when you open the dropdown menu right next to the sphere icons.

I've added an *Area* light to the scene and enabled the *Use Scene Lights* and *Scene World* options. This is the result:

[image: screenshot]